# SQL-command in php-PDO doesn't work - no error is thrown

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am growing more and more desperate! Could somebody lease help me with this PDO problem? I am simply trying to get a "INSERT INTO" command running. It's definitely a problem of syntax because other operations work. There is no error thrown...

this is my code:

```
    $q1 = $db ->prepare("INSERT INTO `bierkasse`.`user` (`ID`, `UID`, `name`, `Oettinger Export 0,5l`, `Oettinger Pils 0,33l`, `Coca Cola 1,0l`, `Fanta 1,0l`, `Erdinger Weissbier 0,5l`, `Beck\'s Pils`, `kontostand`, `menge`) VALUES (NULL, \'879240018263\', \'waldmannnnn\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\')");
```

And this is the table:

[image]

thank you so much!

Comment: You dont need to escape the single quotes in your SQL.

Comment: I'm almost afraid to put in an "answer". I don't like "worms" very much, except when I'm gone fishing ;-)

Comment: If no error is thrown, then enable them; at least `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`.

Comment: That's some table structure. I hope they don't plan on expanding the product range much. And when you prepare statements, you usually do that to bind the variable values to place-holders so that you don't have to inject them in the query directly (which causes all kinds of sql injection problems...).

Comment: Column names with spaces **and** apostrophes! */me backs away slowly*

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute a pdo statement after it is prepared:

```
$q1->execute();
```

On a side note, since you don't use any kind of parameters, and you don't reuse the query multiple times, you could simply `query()` the query:

```
$q1 = $db->query("INSERT ...");
```